# PHP: mail body not complete after sending mail?

Tags: php, email

I am using this code to send my mails:

```
public function sendMail($receiver, $subject, $message){

    $header = "Content-type: text/html";

    mail($receiver, $subject, $message, $header);
}
```

The mail is sent, but the content ($message) is not complete when I open the mail later on. Its a pretty long text but could this be the reason? Why is the mail message cut?

Thanks!

Comment: where is the "From:" in your header?

Comment: Its not there, but adding it does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Use newlines at the end of a header entry

```
$header = "From: ...\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/html\n";
mail($receiver, $subject, $message, $header);
```

Comment: Cann you try opening the HTML message in a browser and see if that gives the same output?

Comment: I do suggest you take a look at SwiftMail, even if we get to the bottom of this. SwiftMail provides an OO interface to send mails which is a lot more readable and easier to use

Comment: I debugged to get the HTML I am using for the message and saved it to a HTML file and viewed it in the browser - looks exactly as I want. So something goes wrong when the mail is sent in the mail function.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how you got it full, but there missing a basic parameters, assigning headers etc.

See the instructions for `mail()` function [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).
For automatic wrapping of HTML use the `wordwrap()` function, if you have HTML content in one line - prevent cutting messages.

Sample code:

```
$from   = "one@mail.com";
$mailto = "two@mail.com";
$reply  = "three@mail.com";

$subject = "Test";
$message = "<html><body><strong>TEST</strong><p>Bla bla bla</p></body></html>";

$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n";
$headers .= "From: $from\nReply-To: $reply\n";

$check = mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $headers);

if ($check) { echo "OK"; } else { echo "ERROR"; }
```

Sample send function:

```
function sendmail($receiver, $subject, $message) {

  $from = "mail@mail.com"; // sender mail

  $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n";
  $headers .= "From: $from\n";

  $check = mail($receiver, $subject, $message, $headers);

  if ($check) { return true; } else { return false; }  
}
```

Or extended sample send function:

```
function sendmail($receiver, $subject, $message) {

  $from_mail = "mail@mail.com"; // sender mail
  $from_name = "Sender Mail"; // mail name

  $from = '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($from_name).'?= <'.$from_mail.'>';

  $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n";
  $headers .= "From: $from\n";

  $check = mail($receiver, '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=', wordwrap($message,76,"\n"), $headers);

  if ($check) { return true; } else { return false; }  
}
```

`base64_encode()` preventive converts input characters, suitable for extended ASCII codes or other non-standard characters (diacritics, logograms etc.).

`wordwrap()` preventive split HTML content before sending, suitable only for HTML content in a single line. Standard is 76 characters per line (see [chunk_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php)), SMTP server should support at least 1,024 characters per line, if not, should be set by yourself.